# Non-convex feasible region in a linear programming problem

Tags: python, optimization

**Problem**:  I am working on a linear programming problem, i.e. a linear objective function to minimize:

$\mathbf{c}\cdot\mathbf{x}$,
where $\mathbf{c},\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{N}$

Subject to constraints:

$\mathbf{x}\geq 0$ and $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{b}$
where $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{MxN}$ and $\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^{M}$

I am using [CyLP](https://github.com/coin-or/CyLP) and the [COIN-OR simplex solver](https://www.coin-or.org/Clp/index.html) to perform the optimization.

**Question**: A feature I would like to be able to build into
the problem is the ability to handle some atypical constraints:

Suppose $x_{i}$ is a component of $\mathbf{x}$. I want to apply the following constraints:

$x_{i} = 0$ or $\mathrm{lb} \leq x_{i} \leq \mathrm{ub}$.

In geometric terms, I want $x_{i}\in [0]\cup [\mathrm{lb}, \mathrm{ub}]$.
Unlike the original problem, where all $x_{i}$ are bounded within convex sets (i.e. non-piecewise intervals).

Is there a good way to modify an LP for the above atypical constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this cannot be done with a continuous LP solver. As you observed, this construct introduces a non-convexity. However, it can be handled by a Mixed Integer Programming (MIP) solver.

$x=0$ or $\ell\le x\le u$ is what is known as a **semi-continuous variable**. Many advanced MIP solvers support this variable type directly.

If a MIP solver does not support this, we can introduce a binary variable $\delta \in \{0,1\}$ and use the constraint:

$$ \ell \cdot \delta \le x \le u \cdot \delta  $$

to simulate a semi-continuous variable.

COIN-OR has a capable MIP solver called CBC (I believe it supports semi-continuous variables directly).